# .NET 3.5 and 4.0 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I'm standing up a new Windows 2008 R2 Web Server.  I've checked the application pool in IIS 7.5, and found that .NET 2.0 is available, but not 3.5 or 4.0.  I would have thought that 2008 R2 would have come at least with 3.5 and possibly 4.0.  Am I wrong about that?

If I have to install 3.5 and 4.0 on this server, where do I get them?  (I'm assuming that it isn't necessarily the same place as client machines get .NET 3.5 and 4.0.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 3.5 with SP1 open an elevated command prompt and copy this line:

```
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3
```

for 4.0: download a the [package from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) and the execute it.

If you do this on Server core, you need to enable different features and download a [special version of dot.NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833) for Server core.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open up Server Manager, then select Add Features, expand .Net Framework 3.5.1 Features and then Tick the box .NET Framework 3.5.1, then follow the wizard.

With .Net 4.0 or later, you will need to download a stand alone and use this.